# Acessar elementos de um array bidimensional através de aritmética de ponteiros

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, array-multidimensional

Estou aprendendo sobre aritmética de ponteiros e cheguei em uma parte onde é dito que arrays multidimensionais são armazenados contiguamente na memória, sendo assim possível acessar seus elementos usando somente um for loop, com aritmética de ponteiros. O exemplo apresentado é esse:

```
#define ARR_ROWS 5
#define ARR_COLS 5

int arr[ARR_ROWS][ARR_COLS];
int *p;

for (p = &arr[0][0]; p <= &arr[ARR_ROWS - 1][ARR_COLS - 1]; ++p)
  *p = 0;
```

que funciona perfeitamente.
Entretanto, quando tentei fazer uma pequena modificação teste do for loop, o programa começou a dar crash (stack corrompida ou algo do tipo).
A mudança que eu fiz foi de `p <= &arr[ARR_ROWS - 1][ARR_COLS - 1]` para `p < &arr[ARR_ROWS][ARR_COLS]`.
As condições `x < N` e `x <= N - 1` não são equivalentes? Por que o programa crasha?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sim, as expressões `x <= N - 1` e `x < N` são equivalentes, porém `p <= &arr[ARR_ROWS - 1][ARR_COLS - 1]` não é equivalente a `p < &arr[ARR_ROWS][ARR_COLS]`, é equivalente a `p < &arr[ARR_ROWS - 1][ARR_COLS]`.

Todo elemento do *array*, incluindo 5 elementos que não pertencem ao array, possui endereço menor que `&arr[ARR_ROWS][ARR_COLS]` (causando um [accesso impróprio de memória](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transbordamento_de_dados)):

```
&arr[0][0] -> X X X X X
              X X X X X
              X X X X X
              X X X X X
              X X X X X
              # # # # # # <- &arr[ARR_ROWS][ARR_COLS]
```

Todo elemento do *array* possui endereço menor ou igual a `&arr[ARR_ROWS - 1][ARR_COLS - 1]`:

```
&arr[0][0] -> X X X X X
              X X X X X
              X X X X X
              X X X X X
              X X X X X <- &arr[ARR_ROWS - 1][ARR_COLS - 1]
```

Todo elemento do *array* possui endereço menor que `&arr[ARR_ROWS - 1][ARR_COLS]`:

```
&arr[0][0] -> X X X X X
              X X X X X
              X X X X X
              X X X X X
              X X X X X # <- &arr[ARR_ROWS - 1][ARR_COLS]
```

Comment: Consegui entender agora. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score -2):

Para acessar elementos de um array bidimensional através de ponteiros em C, você pode usar o seguinte código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  // cria um array bidimensional de 3 linhas e 4 colunas
  int array[3][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};

  // cria um ponteiro para int e o inicializa com o endereço do primeiro elemento do array
  int *p = &array[0][0];

  // acessa o elemento da linha 2, coluna 3 usando o ponteiro
  int elemento = *(p + (2 * 4 + 3));  // equivalente a array[2][3]
  printf("%d\n", elemento);  // imprime 11
}
```